# How I can poll messages from Solace queue (instead of default pushing behavior)?

Tags: c#, .net, messaging, distributed-computing, solace

I'd like to write parallel execution module based on Solace. And I use [request-reply](https://dev.solace.com/samples/solace-samples-dotnet/request-reply/) schema for this.

I have:

- Multiple message consumers, which publish messages into the same queue.
- Multiple message producers, which read queue and create reply messages.
- Message execution time is between 10 seconds to 10 minutes.
- Queue access type is [non-exclusive](https://docs.solace.com/Features/Endpoints.htm#Queues) (e.g. it does round-robin between all consumers).
- Each producer and consumer is asynchronous, e.g. Solace API blocks execution during the connection only.

What I'd like to have: **if produces works on the message, it should not receive any other messages.** This is extremely important, because some tasks blocks executor for several minutes, however other executors can be free after couple of seconds.

Scheme below can be workable (possible), however blocking code appears below. I'd like to avoid it.

```
while(true)
{
    var inputMessage = flow.ReceiveMsg( /*timeout 1s*/1_000); // <--- blocking code, I'd like to avoid it

    flow.Ack(inputMessage.ADMessageId);

    var reply = await ProcessMessageAsync(inputMessage); // execute plus handle exceptions

    session.SendReply(inputMessage, reply)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages are only pushed to the consuming applications.

That being said, your desired behavior can be obtained by setting the "max-delivered-unacked-msgs-per-flow" on your queue to 1.
This means that each consumer bound to the queue is only allowed to have 1 outstanding unacknowledged messages.
The next message will be only sent to the consumer after it has acknowledged the message.

Details about this feature can be found [here](https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Configuring-Queues.htm#managing_guaranteed_messaging_1810020758_455709).

Do note that your code snippet does not appear to be valid.
[`IFlow.ReceiveMsg`](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/net/html/20515991-8c0d-693d-22de-fc4881aac17a.htm) is only used in transacted sessions, which makes use of [`ITransactedSession.Commit`](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/net/html/9629a196-4e6f-16d1-fc22-bc25e427faaa.htm) to acknowledge messages.